# After "longtable", label numbering starts with 2 instead of 1

Tags: tables, numbering, longtable, labels

I am using a longtable because my table exceeds one page. When I want to label the table, numbering starts with 2 (when the label is below the table). When I label the table on top of it, it starts with 1, but the next table continues with 3 instead of 2. When changing `longtable` to `tabular`, it works with no flaws.

See simplified code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
%   \captionof{table}{tab1
%   \label{Tab:tab0}}
    \begin{longtable}[h]{ll}
        a & b
    \end{longtable}
    \captionof{table}{tab1
    \label{Tab:tab1}}

    \begin{tabular}[h]{llllll}
    asdf & asdf & adf & Dasdfasdf & asdfasdfn & asdf
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{tab2
    \label{Tab:tab2}}

\end{document}
```

I know I might should use `\begin{table}`, but somehow I wrote the whole document without it and added labels in the end. Because I don't use `\begin{table}`, I am using the workaround `\captionof` which I found somewhere on the internet.

Comment: I assume "label the table"  refers to adding a caption. You can directly use `\caption` inside of a `longtable` environment to do so. There is no need for `\captionof` here.

Comment: oh, simple as that :P thx a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Although a `longtable` does not float, you can nevertheless use the `\caption` command inside of a `longtable` environment and your tables will be numbered correctly:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}[h]{ll}
    \caption{tab1\label{Tab:tab0}}\\
        a & b
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{tabular}[h]{llllll}
    asdf & asdf & adf & Dasdfasdf & asdfasdfn & asdf
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{tab2
    \label{Tab:tab2}}

\end{document}
```

Since you can have multiple `\caption` commands inside of one `longtable` (One caption for the first page and a different one for all following pages), the `table` counter is not increased for each `\caption` command but once for the whole `longtable` environment. Thus, if you want a `longtable` without any caption, you must manually decrease the `table` counter by one, for example by using `\addtocounter{table}{-1}`.

Comment: sorry about that: not the best part of the longtable design